# argument not found in R function

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

Im trying to write a R function to summarize some data.
The code I wrote is below:

```
    function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4){
    arg4 <- ddply(arg1, arg3, summarise,
    N = length(arg2),
    mean = mean(arg2, na.rm = T),
    median = median(arg2, na.rm = T),
    var = var(arg2, na.rm = T),
    sd = sqrt(var),
    se = sd/sqrt(N)
    )}
```

My data is in this format:

```
   ID.1   biome seed_origin      soil espess_average  area
13   13 Cerrado     Assis_4 I_Cardoso     36.66667  67.2
14   14 Cerrado     Assis_4 I_Cardoso     29.66667 120.0
31   31 Cerrado     Assis_4 I_Cardoso     29.33333  72.6
33   33 Cerrado     Assis_4 I_Cardoso     32.00000  78.0
37   37 Cerrado     Assis_4 I_Cardoso     31.00000  56.1
42   42 Cerrado     Assis_4 I_Cardoso     48.33333  59.5
```

So I've called my function with the following arguments:

```
sumarizeSE(folhas_esp_area, "espess_average", "biome", "cdata16Folha.espess");
```

and get the message: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'arg2' not found "

What am I doing wrong? Is it in the function code or in the way Im calling it?

Putting espess_average without quotes didnt solve it.

Comment: Read about how to pass characters as variables in functions.

Comment: `ddply` is made for interactive use and works with *unquoted* column names. This is great for interactive use and terrible for programming. It is difficult to write your own custom function that uses unquoted column names. You might want to re-write the function not using `plyr`, (`data.table`, base functions like `aggregate` or `tapply`) or the more current `dplyr` which has a vignette, [Programming with `dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), teaching you how to approach this.